# How do I generate Psuedo-random numbers in pact. Why does now() or rand() violate PACT's core principles?

Tags: pact-lang

When writing a bar dice game on PACT for a tutorial,  I needed to roll a series of dice in rapid succession.  After noticing no RAND() capability or NOW() capability I was stuck because my .repl and .pact files were not yet sent to test-net.   Therefore, the chain-data object was not useful in this instance as it just refers to start epoch until pushed.  (was running directly in Ubuntu bash)

Obviously, we can just make an API into a front end and pass in unique times, hash them up, and mod by 6 to roll a die. However, this led us to think about PACT and why NOW() and RAND() is not allowed.  We must admit we were stumped on this one as they are so critical in so many applications.

Is this because it opens up PACT to change of state and therefore isn't secure?  Please teach us about the theoretical issues behind opening these HASKELL functions up as a core PACT function.

Comment: You should ask precise questions that can be answered with a precise answered. Asking to "teach haskell theory" is probably too broad

Comment: who's combative attitude?

Answer (score 2):

As a disclaimer - you will never have secure randomness on the blockchain.

There are work arounds for rand

One way is

1. Get the current hash of the time
2. Convert it to base 64
3. Convert base 64 to normal number

```
 (str-to-int 
    64 
    (base64-encode 
        (hash (at "block-time" (chain-data) ))  
    ) 
)
```

As to your problem around " I was stuck because my .repl and .pact files were not yet sent to test-net"

You can set the time variable via your repl files manually like so

`(env-chain-data { "block-time" : (time "2021-04-28T00:00:00Z") })`

Comment: Notice that I mentioned that I had not launched to test-net or main-net and therefore the chain-object was not useful for tests.  Hence I wondered why these critical functions were not included in base pact as they are in Haskell.  https://hackage.haskell.org/package/time.  The question I think was extremely simple.  What makes NOW() and RAND() insecure?

Comment: the function chain-data is included in base pact. You can use it from repl as well as on-chain.

Comment: You didn't even read the question where chain-data was clearly not a solution and not an answer to the question at all.  @georgep    At least read the question.

Comment: >  I was stuck because my .repl and .pact files were not yet sent to test-net
You can update the chain time locally if you're testing via repl

Comment: @KDAbet updated the answer to include how to do this.
As a sidenote - this probably could've been 2 or 3 questions, like
1. How to get a random number in Pact
or
2. How to get a random number in your local .repl environment
3. Why does now() and rand() violate core Pact principles.

It's a bit hard to answer multiple questions at once, even with good intent its easy for readers to miss some details

Comment: That's true,  but the fundamental question is why no RAND() or NOW() which is 3.   I got some half answer in builders telegram where the async push in fetch.send would result in random numbers being mismatched which makes sense.   but then I asked why can't I send a request to run (randlist int) on one chain,  mine it,  then propagate that message to all 20 chains?  I guess they just don't want a stateful function being opened up because it opens up function purity headaches.

Answer (score 0):

All smart contract languages must be 100% deterministic.  That means that when you run something with the same inputs it gives the same output every time, no matter when or on what computer you run it.  NOW() and RAND() are not deterministic.  They give different results every time you call them.  So they can't exist in a smart contract language, full stop.

Comment: I think no-one expects a 100% purely random and secure RAND() function from a smart contract. Most languages are deterministic and have RAND() functions which aren't secure to help developers out.

This doesn't explain why there isn't a `PSEUDO_RAND()` which takes a seed number in it and uses curr time.
I'm not sure if possible - but if the GAS costs are computed as execution happens, then the gas used upto when PSEUDO_RAND is called, could be added to make things more random

Comment: There is a function like this that takes a seed value and gives you back something unpredictable that is a deterministic function of its input: [hash](https://pact-language.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pact-functions.html#hash).  It doesn't use current time, but rather does the more general thing of letting you use whatever you want as input.